# Filter data in table with CASE function

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a slight problem. I need to write a query, that selects 3 columns in the table `[dbo].[BO_POS_Rcp_Headers]` , but in case if one column contains value other than R100, it needs to print 'FAIL' instead of the incorrect row.
Link to the table picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tVcb.jpg

As you can see, row 8 has a different value than all other rows in column "WERKS". What I can't understand is how to Make it so that when I launch the query, it display FAIL instead of row 8.

```
SELECT 
WERKS, timestamp, total
CASE
    WHERE WERKS = 'R100' THEN ?
    ELSE 'FAIL'
FROM [dbo].[BO_POS_Rcp_Headers]
```

Comment: do remember that in your question above, you are missing a comma behind total... just a suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with your syntax.

**Example:**

```
CASE
    WHEN 1.condition THEN result1
    WHEN 2.condition THEN result2
    WHEN 3.condition THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END as [Table alias]
```

Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**Data example:**

```
Declare  @TableName table(werks varchar(250), timestamp DATE,total varchar(250))

insert into @TableName values
('R100','2015-10-02','0.17'),
('R100','2015-10-02','0.17'),
('R100','2016-07-02','15' ),
('R100','2015-10-22','0.42'),
('R10','2015-11-02','0.45'),
('R10','2015-10-02','12')

SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN WERKS = 'R100' THEN 'R100'
      ELSE 'FAIL'
    END [WERKS] , timestamp, total
FROM @TableName
```

**Outcome example:**

```
WERKS   |timestamp  |total
--------------------------
R100    |2015-10-02 |0.17
R100    |2015-10-02 |0.17
R100    |2016-07-02 |15
R100    |2015-10-22 |0.42
FAIL    |2015-11-02 |0.45
FAIL    |2015-10-02 |12
```

**Try this for you**

```
SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN WERKS = 'R100' THEN 'R100'
      ELSE 'FAIL'
    END [WERKS] , timestamp, total
FROM [dbo].[BO_POS_Rcp_Headers]
```

Comment: I get an error saying 
Line 2 - invalid column name for all the columns
Line 3 - Invalid syntax near 'CASE'
Line 6 - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WERKS' Expecting CONVERSATION

All of this is done in Server Management studio using transact-sql

Comment: Would you please try again?

Comment: If this helps you, please remember check this as your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    timestamp, total,
    CASE
      WHEN WERKS <> 'R100' THEN 'FAIL'
      ELSE WERKS
    END [WERKS]
FROM [dbo].[BO_POS_Rcp_Headers]
```

I missed a comma after "total"